# docker service create doesn't find image

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I run docker service create --mode global foo myrepo/foo-img:0.1, it works in that it starts the service, but if foo-img:0.1 does not exist on a node in the swarm, that node emits the following error:

```
<containerid>   \_ foo    myrepo/foo:0.1  <snip>  "No such image: myrepo/foo-img:0.1"
```

If I pull myrepo/foo-img:0.1 on each node then it works fine.

Is there a workaround for this other than pulling the image on each node in the swarm?

Comment: to start a container, the node needs the image. So all the nodes need access to a repository where they can download it.

Comment: Correct. However, all nodes do have access to the private repository, the issue is that they are not or can not pull the image. I am looking at the --with-registry-auth argument as a possible solution, but I don't see any documentation for how to specify credentials using it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple. Use the`--with-registry-auth` parameter. This parameter uses the same authentication that is used for your current session. So, to make this work you simply:

```
# docker login -u xxx -pass yyy https://myrepo.com
# service create --with-registry-auth foo myrepo.com/foo-img:0.1
```

Assuming that you successfully logged in, the service will pull the image from the repo to each node as needed. Not sure exactly what happens behind the scenes, but it works for deploying to all nodes currently in the cluster! Thanks to the help from the folks at github/docker!

Comment: Great this works! Is there no way to use the images on the manager, not being a repo - just if you know?

Comment: I am not aware of another way. My initial investigation was to try to do something like you suggest, but didn't have any luck. If you do happen to find another please share.